# Calculate speed by distance and friction

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas, physics

I am writing a game in Javascript, Canvas, HTML5, and I just found a big problem, related to advanced maths. The game is in flat 2D, so you see the world from over. That means there is no gravity, only friction.

CODE:

```
var friction = 0.97

var target = {
  x: 70,
  y: 90,
}

var ball = {
  x: 10,
  y: 20,
  vx: 0,
  vy: 0,
}
var dx = ball.x - target.x
var dy = ball.y - target.y
var angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
var dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) // <--- AS FAR AS I'VE COME
var speed = ??? // <--- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
ball.vx = Math.cos(angle) * speed
ball.vy = Math.sin(angle) * speed

function update() {
  ball.vx *= friction
  ball.vy *= friction
  ball.x += ball.vx
  ball.y += ball.vy

  // Drawing and other unneccesary things to involve here

  window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

update()
```

So, my question is: How do I calculate the speed in the section where I create the ball, to make the ball stop at exactly the targets x and y position? As far as I've come I've only calculated the starting distance between the ball and the targets position.. Soo, any ideas? Is there an equation for this?

Comment: You would have to explain what your game is about in more detail. If your ball has no initial speed and there is no acceleration, the ball will never reach its target, thats simple physics. I think you have a conceptual problem and no mathematical problem.

Comment: You've to decide that yourself. There's no speed without time, so you've to decide how many pixels per second you want your ball to move. Also you've to decide, how many pixels per second your ball increases speed in a second. You can also use a formula of the steady speed `s = v*t`, but you still need to know the time. (I'm sorry for the terminology here, I've just found a huge hole in my english vocabulary.)

Comment: I want the grenade to land at cursor instead of loading up power by holding mouse and only shooting in direction.

Comment: sry spam, a glitch just. it's a big game, not so many things but alot of code, I made the game and graphics myself, but the sounds are just downloaded simply

Comment: pretty much code, thats why I didn't explain the real problem

Comment: No JQuery, makes it easier :D

Comment: @Murplyx Read these articles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity ; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration.
Quote: When only the object's initial velocity is known, this expression can be used:
`dx = u * dt + a * dt^2 / 2`
where: `u` - initial velocity, `dt` - time interval

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand, I mean like how am I going to put that in the code? ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want the sum for i from 1 to ∞ over the term (speed × friction<sup>i</sup>), and you want the result to equal dist. This is an infinite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), the limit of which is speed×friction/(1 − friction).

[image: Formula of infinite sum]

So simply solve the equation for speed, and you obtain:

[image: Solving the formula for speed]

```
speed = (1/friction - 1)*dist
```

Comment: Are you sure it will stop at x 70 y 90 if I do:  var speed = (1 + friction) / friction * dist ???

Comment: @Murplyx: I had a mistake in my formula, basically a sign error. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, I thought so when I used the calculator