# Closing towards a point, independent of the frame rate?

Tags: math, 3d, language-agnostic, logic

I'm making a Camera class in 3D that closes in towards a point, slowing down and easing into stopping.  To do this regularly is pretty simple:

```
// positions are vectors, dampening is a scalar, usually set to ~0.9

currentPosition += (targetPosition - currentPosition) * dampening;
```

However, this is locked to the framerate, assuming it's executed exactly once per frame.

How would one best implement this behaviour that's dependent on time, instead of frame rate or times executed?

Answer (score 0):

A short experiment (and if you need a bit of induction) shows that after *n* frames you are at

```
targetPosition*(1 - (1 - dampening)^n) + currentPosition*(1 - dampening)^n
```

so to make this time-dependent, write

```
targetPosition*(1 - pow(1 - dampening, t)) + currentPosition*pow(1 - dampening, t)
```

where dampening is now per unit of time, and time might even be fractional.

Your question reminds me of [Calculate speed by distance and friction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21696384/1468366).